# Ionic Routig using Vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, html, ionic-framework, html-components

I am new to ionic framework and currently stuck on a project where I am required to implement a simple navigation. I am using ionic for the project with vanilla js.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<ion-router>
    <ion-route url="/new-page" component="new-page"></ion-route>
  </ion-router>
  <ion-nav></ion-nav>

   
    <ion-tabs>
        <!-- Tab views -->
        <ion-tab tab="new-page">
            <ion-nav></ion-nav>
        </ion-tab>

      
        <!-- Tab bar -->
        <ion-tab-bar slot="bottom">
          <ion-tab-button tab="new-page" selected=true>
            <ion-icon name="person"></ion-icon>
          </ion-tab-button>
          
        </ion-tab-bar>
      </ion-tabs>
```

I have a custom html component in a js file which is being rendered here. However I cannot connect my tab button with that new component.

I can't wrap my head around this. How should I go about navigating between two screens?

Answer (score 0):

1. Ionic has in-build functionality for routing, it Is suggested to follow for the integrity of the project.
   Example with Ionic Angular:https://ionicframework.com/docs/angular/navigation
2. If you are looking to implement custom routing and functions using Vanilla JS,Core Cordova library is recommended - https://cordova.apache.org/ can be integrated with UI library like Boostrap easily.

Comment: Well I have made some progress with navigation but I am not sure if that is correct or not because though I am able to navigate but the browser console gives an error saying [ion-router] the path does not match any route

And in the url of my app I see the following:

news.html#/newpage

However I want something link this to happen:
/newpage

Comment: Are you using Ionic - Angular ? If yes can you post your .ts file for routing ?